# Localize a non-English app using Base Localization

Tags: localization, ios8, xcode6

Since Base localization is the way to go, I am a bit puzzled how to localize an existing app that was not written in English.

Let's say I've developed an app only for the German market so all XIBs and Storyboards etc. are in German, although the Localization area in the project info says "English".

[image: Screenshort of 'Localizations' section]

This doesn't hurt until you would like to actually develop an English version of the app. Next step would be to separate English and German localizations. So I add "German" to the list and get a "de.lproj" folder with .strings files for each XIB and storyboard.

But let's assume I am not that good at English and would like to give the German (*Base*) texts to a translating service.

Great, I'll export them using *Editor > Export For Localization ...*. But wait, the xliff file says  `source-language='en'` and `target-language='de'`. This isn't true, the app is already in German, I want it to be the other way round.

What am I missing? How can I say that the app was actually written in German the first time and now I'd like to add English as a translation?

Comment: FYI I filed a bug report at Apple. (Un-)fortunately it was not an original bug, but reported before ;-)